# How can tasks which have to deal with uiviews and bounds work asynchronously in background thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uiview, grand-central-dispatch

I have to manage around 40 tasks serially, without blocking the UI and those tasks have a lot to do with UIView bounds and frames and basically everything that's related to UIViews and yes any view update has to be coded in the main thread, but what's the point of using any serial/global queue (I mean any background queue) if my whole code has to be inside main_queue which is inside a global/serial queue? I mean all my tasks should look like this right? and does my serial queue do anything to make it work asynchronously and efficiently in this way?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t imageProcessingQueue;
_imageProcessingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mySerialQueue",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(self.imageProcessingQueue, ^(){
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        //Do all the image processing + UI depending work here.
      };
    });
```

1.First question, is the approach above the proper way to do it asynchronously but also?

2. Second question, If doing UI tasks in main thread is okay then why do I still get the warning

> [UView init] must be called from main thread only

even though I do that in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(){
        //Do all the task here};` which is main thread. 
Here is what my task looks like.

```
-(void)task1{
     if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:_bgImageView]) {
        [_bgImageView removeFromSuperview];
        _bgImageView.image= nil;
        _bgImageView= nil;

    }
    if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:_fgImageView]) {
        [_fgImageView removeFromSuperview];
        _fgImageView.image= nil;
        _fgImageView= nil;
    }
    for (UIView* views in mainView.subviews){
        [views removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //Foreground Layer Effect
    fgGPUFilter = [[GPUImageMonochromeFilter alloc]init];
    [(GPUImageMonochromeFilter *)fgGPUFilter setColor:(GPUVector4)
     {115.0/255.0, 184.0/255.0, 178.0/255.0, 1.0}];
    [(GPUImageMonochromeFilter *)fgGPUFilter setIntensity: 0.4];
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_bgImage];
    [stillImageSource addTarget:fgGPUFilter];
    [fgGPUFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [stillImageSource processImage];
    UIImage *fgImgWithEffect = [fgGPUFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

    //GPUFilter clearing the cach for second filter.
    fgGPUFilter =nil;
    [[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] purgeAllUnassignedFramebuffers];
    stillImageSource=nil;
    [self.view addSubview:mainView];

    UIImageView * bgImgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:_bgImage];
    [mainView addSubview:bgImgV];
    [bgImgV setFrame:imageRect];

    CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path=forgroungPath.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.bounds=pathRect;
    CGFloat xRect=(CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path).origin.x)* -1;
    CGFloat yRect=(CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path).origin.y)* -1;
    [shapeLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xRect, yRect)];
    shapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pathRect), CGRectGetMidY(pathRect));
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [shapeLayer fillColor];
    UIGraphicsImageRenderer*renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc]initWithBounds:imageRect];
    UIImage*shapeImage=[renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext*_Nonnull context){
        [shapeLayer renderInContext: context.CGContext];
    }];
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage new];
    @autoreleasepool{
        CIImage * inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:shapeImage];
        CIContext * context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        CIFilter * clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
        [clampFilter setDefaults];
        [clampFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        CIFilter * blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
        [blurFilter setValue:clampFilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [blurFilter setValue:@8.0f forKey:@"inputRadius"];
        CIImage *result = [blurFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        CIImage * croppedCIImage=[result imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0,0,mainView.bounds.size.width*scale,mainView.bounds.size.height*scale)];
        CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:croppedCIImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
        resultImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale:shapeImage.scale orientation:_bgImage.imageOrientation];
    }

    UIImageView *fgImgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:resultImage];
    [mainView addSubview:fgImgV];
    [fgImgV setFrame:AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(resultImage.size, fgImgV.frame)];
    bgImgV.layer.mask=fgImgV.layer;

    UIGraphicsImageRenderer * renderer2 = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc]initWithBounds:bgImgV.layer.bounds];
    UIImage*finalFG=[renderer2 imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext*_Nonnull context3){
        [bgImgV.layer renderInContext: context3.CGContext];
    }];

    [fgImgV removeFromSuperview];
    fgImgV.image= nil;
    fgImgV=nil;
    [bgImgV removeFromSuperview];
    bgImgV.image= nil;
    bgImgV=nil;
    [mainView removeFromSuperview];

    UIView * finalView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*0.6)];
    [self.view addSubview:finalView];

    //Background Layer Effect
    bgGPUFilter = [[GPUImagePolkaDotFilter alloc]init];
    [(GPUImagePolkaDotFilter *)bgGPUFilter setFractionalWidthOfAPixel:0.03];
    GPUImagePicture *bgStillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_bgImage];
    [bgStillImageSource addTarget:bgGPUFilter];
    [bgGPUFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [bgStillImageSource processImage];
    UIImage *finalBG = [bgGPUFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    bgGPUFilter =nil;
    [[GPUImageContext sharedFramebufferCache] purgeAllUnassignedFramebuffers];
    bgStillImageSource=nil;

    //To show two UIImageviews on top of eachother.
    _bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:finalBGImg];
    _fgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:finalFGImg];
    [finalView addSubview:_bgImageView];
    [finalView addSubview:_fgImageView];
    [_bgImageView setFrame:AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(finalBG.size, finalView.bounds)];
    [_fgImageView setFrame:AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(finalFG.size, finalView.bounds)];
}
```

Comment: It is not ok that you get the warning. Please show where you initialize `UIView`.

Comment: The _calculation_ doesn't have to be on the main thread, just the actual setting of the view's properties.

Comment: Basically if i do anything (create or modify) inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^(){ //here};` I will get the error. @shallowThought

Comment: Due to the fact that each task consists of 120 lines, Creating, modifying, releasing them from memory, setting them to nil etc for each time Im modifying each UI depending object, I need to switch between main_queue and my serial queue?! that would make my code muchhhh longer and uglier. there's no way I could do it better? the task is long I dont know if i can share it here. @JoshCaswell

Comment: I just put my code for my first task as an example. @shallowThought

Comment: Show where you call  `task1`.

Comment: I either call it in viewdidload like [self task1]; or i make a block and use that in a dispatch queue again in viewdidload but i havnt applied any of my tasks in main_queue inside serial queue because i get the warning for doing UI calculations inside a thread. @shallowThought

Comment: It is not really possible to help you without seeing the real code.

Comment: It is the actual code i posted here! There's nothing skipped, there are two UIImageviews  in which they have uiimages, this task processes and renders Each of those uiimages that are needed to be shown inside those UIImageviews @shallowThought

Comment: If this is the complete relevant code, `task1` is never called. Background: I highly suspect that you either _think_ you call `task1` only on the main thread but accidentally call it from another one, or, that you _think_ the warning comes from the code in `task1`, but comes from somewhere else.

Comment: As I said, I call it in viewdidload and it works! It does workbut it takes so much memory and makes the UI not responsive,  but maybe I should edit my code to make it more clear @shallowThought .